# monitoring desktop heap memory

Tags: windows

Is there any way to figure out which application is using up all the desktop heap memory?

For an explanation of 'desktop heap' see [this MSDN blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ntdebugging/archive/2007/01/04/desktop-heap-overview.aspx).

EDIT: If you don't know what "desktop heap memory" is please don't answer.

EDIT2: if you don't know what "desktop heap memory" is don't vote to close the question.

Answer (score 6):

Disclaimer: I work for Microsoft, and these are my personal thoughts and experiences which may or may not reflect current or future Microsoft policies/procedures/etc.

I know this is old, but since I stumbled across it I wanted to provide some feedback/answers.

Desktop Heap Monitor does not work on Vista+.  DHeapMon depended on the ability to patch kernel binaries to track desktop heap- this behavior is blocked, which is why it doesn't work.

To monitor desktop heap yourself, all you can do is look at user objects (unfortunately).

To get a complete answer, you can open a support ticket with Microsoft and with a kernel or complete dump (NOT a process dump!) and they can inspect the heap and provide you some information.  It is extracted from the dump file via a debugger extension, which I wrote.

Limitations:

1. Only works from kernel mode. Even though a desktop heap mapping exists in user mode, the extension does not support it. Even if I added support for user mode debugging of desktop heap, it would be limited as some of the related data is only in kernel mode. Changes on recent builds of Windows 10 might restrict it further, so I have not invested time to add user mode support.
2. It can't measure what isn't in the dump. In other words, if the desktop heap is missing pages it will do its best but it will obviously lose accuracy.
3. Does not support Windows 10 build 1809 or Server 2019, yet, due to changes to the heap manager.

Happy coding!

Comment: That's quite unbelievable that a critical metric like this can't actually be monitored in Windows. Thanks for the clarification though.

Answer (score 4):

According to this [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ntdebugging/archive/2007/01/04/desktop-heap-overview.aspx) post you should look for the user objects. 
To find the bad application you can configure the USER Objects column within Process Explorer. Then sort descending by user objects. User Objects are all GUI objects like Windows, Toolbars, Icons, Cursors ... The process with the highest values is very likely the bad one.

Direct link to download: [DHeapMon](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ntdebugging/archive/2007/01/04/desktop-heap-overview.aspx) from microsoft.

Comment: I think user objects is only one of the ways to leak desktop heap.  There are no GUI apps running here, only server apps, so it is unlikely to help; I'm hoping to a clear view of the type: app a uses 10Kb of desktop heap memory, app b...

Comment: Even for server processes are Windows created. Think about the hidden Window COM uses for its STA message pump. Since Windows is all about COM there are quite a few windows around even in server apps. As far as I know there is no way to list the desktop heap usage per process. Since the objects are handles there is no way to tell how much desktop heap memory this or that window, icon is using.

Comment: I'm sure there is a way, but it would require having a kernel driver. debugheap diag tool from MS is a kernel driver. Unfortunately it only shows the total usage, but not who is using it.  You are right that server processes will have GUI objects, but I don't think they are likely to leak... And there are definitely non-gui related objects which use dh.  Still worth a try, of course.

Comment: Sorry that I cannot help you more specifically but your question is rather generic. What server do have how many processes are running on them? Can you try to kill some and to check which processes are the likely ones. As an alternative you could attach Windbg on all processes and dump the stack for all call to the system calls listed in the blog post and sort them by process and hit count. This approach does work for sure but it is a complex undertaking. It does get easier if you have more hints or a suspicion what process has the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it within your program, C++ can use WMI to find the culprit.

Comment: not my program.  there is something on the server leaking desktop heap memory and I need to figure out what it is.  Does WMI specifically have a hook for desktop heap?  Link please?

Comment: ... but can't you just use TaskManager like SLaks suggested?  Choose View / Select Columns